# How can I update a page in real time after receiving a POST request in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to be able to have a PHP page that can allow one person to send a POST request to it with information and then every user who already has the page open will automatically be updated to reflect the new information in the POST request without refreshing the page.

I have a bit of experience with PHP and I can handle receiving a POST request and reading/writing to a database, I just need to know how (if possible) I can have this PHP script send this new information to all connected clients without requiring them to refresh the page.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You need to use `jquery` and `ajax`. If you are not comfortable with this two guys then your only chance is to refresh the page.

Comment: @Franco I'm using ajax from another page to create the POST request to this page. I'm not super familiar with ajax but if I could get pointed in the right direction I would love to learn how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ scroll to the bottom of the page and you'll see how it's sending requests to another web page. You should be able to find your way from there.

Comment: If you are looking for something like socket.io for php, then might I suggest [ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: @Rawrskyes and ippi Thank you for the suggestions, I'll be sure to look at them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok Aaron, I have to go on here because there is no much space in the comment to explain this.

If you are already using `ajax` to post the data to the database
then you can do it so:

in the page you need to be refreshed add an other `ajax request` in order to retrieve the posted values from the database and wrap it in a function, as example:

```
function get_post(){
    var Url = 'here the url that points to your php script'
    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { //if needed you need to pass here the parameters },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        //here assign the returned data to the html element
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

after that you will need this in order to call the function on periodical intervals:

```
setInterval(function(){
    get_post()         
},5000);
```

This will execute the above mentioned funcion every 5 seconds (adjust this value following your needs)
The page will refresh without reloading.

NOTE: I don't know what you are storing and what you are going to show, so depending of what you are planning to do you will need to add some additional code in the returned response and maybe you will need to pre-format your outputted `html` directly in your `php` script so you can display it in your page in one go.

I hope this will give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, this helps greatly. I think I can figure it out with this.

Comment: This is a spot on answer, however I would like to expand the question: Is there a way to get the data to the front-end as soon as a request arrives. In other words, something like an interrupt pin on a micro controller, which would raise a flag for the front-end (js), based on which a handler function is fired?